# How can I manage microservices on personal linux bare metal?

Tags: java, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Let's say we have this situation:

1. One Eureka server in a docker container running on default port
2. A bunch on services, let's say foo.jar, bar.jar, ..., foobar.jar running on random ports ( `server.port=0` )

If I have to restart a service, how can I uniquely identify it?
 
How can I get the PID of a single java process among the many running?

What is the best method to manage the start/stop/restart of microservices?
Using containers for each service is the only solution ?

[edit]

**JPS** seems not working properly, I have a jar running on port 80

```sh
# netstat -nlp | grep ':80'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      9783/java
```

but `# jps -lV` doesn't list it

Comment: What Java version? There are some nice options in 9+

Comment: 8. but i can easily switch to 11

Comment: In 9+ you can do this: `ProcessHandle.current().pid()`. Otherwise I would say the most common approach I've seen is to use a startup script that keeps track of the process and its pid